# How to get the data from the first cell in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` that is populated using `fetchResultController` because I'm using core data, and I want to get the first content in the table view (its a string) and assign it to a label in a different screen. So this `label` will always present the content of the first cell in the table view.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't. This is backwards. You don't get data from a cell, you put data into a cell. Therefore that data has to be stored somewhere (possibly an array?) so the first time in the array will contain the data that you need. Never "get" data from the view.

Comment: You should read this data from core data, however the method - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath should allow you to read data from populated table view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is in objective-c but you can easily covert it to swift:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
NSManagedObject *record = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
```

Record is your object for first row in first section in the table view.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the data from a specific cell and show it on next screen

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "edit" {
            let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let taskController:TaskDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TaskDetailViewController
            let task:Tasks = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Tasks
            taskController.task = task
        }
    }
```

You must check this tutorial [CoreData tutoiral in Swift using NSFetchedResultsController](http://rshankar.com/coredata-tutoiral-in-swift-using-nsfetchedresultcontroller/)

These tutorials would be of more help
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/ and this 
http://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: hehe does apple pays you to promote swift? thanks for the help buddy @Omer Waqas Khan

Comment: always learning something new then whether its swift or assembly  ;) ... you are welcome

Comment: sorry but i don't do swift yet, next time

Comment: The code is pretty much identical to what you would do with Objective-C. You don't need to "do Swift" to understand it. But you should probably being "doing Swift" anyway :)